# Python multiprocessing BETWEEN Amazon cloud instances

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm looking to run a long-running python analysis process on a few Amazon EC2 instances. The code already runs using the python `multiprocessing` module and can take advantage of all cores on a single machine.

The analysis is completely parellel and each instance does not need to communicate with any of the others. All of the work is "file-based" and each process works on each file indivually ... so I was planning on just mounting the same S3 volume across all of the nodes.

I was wondering if anyone knew of any tutorials (or had any suggestions) for setting up the multiprocessing environment so I can run it on an arbitrary number of compute-instances at the same time.

Comment: if you need any more information to answer the quesion then just leave me a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the docs give you a good setup for [running multiprocessing on multiple machines](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager). Using s3 is a good way to share files across ec2 instances, but with multiprocessing you can share queues and pass data.

if you can use hadoop for parallel tasks, it is a very good way to extract parallelism across machines, but if you need a lot of IPC then building your own solution with multiprocessing isn't that bad.

just make sure you put your machines in the same security groups :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [dumbo](http://dumbotics.com/2009/12/23/dumbo-on-amazon-emr/). It is a python wrapper for Hadoop that is compatible with Amazon Elastic MapReduce. Write a little wrapper around your code to integrate with dumbo. Note that you probably need a map-only job with no reduce step.

Answer (score 0):

I've been digging into IPython recently, and it looks like it supports parallel processing accross multiple hosts right out of the box:

http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/html/parallel/index.html